# How to connect a 3D points with a distance threshold Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of 3D points lets say A as shown below,

```
   A=[
    -0.240265581092000  0.0500598627544876  1.20715641293013
    -0.344503191645519  0.390376667574812   1.15887540716612
    -0.0931248606994074 0.267137193112796   1.24244644549763
    -0.183530493218807  0.384249186312578   1.14512014134276
    -0.0201358671977785 0.404732019283683   1.21816745283019
    -0.242108038906952  0.229873488902244   1.24229940627651
    -0.391349107031230  0.262170158259873   1.23856838565023
    ]
```

what I want to do is to connect 3D points with lines which only have distance less than a specific threshold `T`. I want to get a list of pairs of points needed to be connected. Such as,

```
[ 
( -0.240265581092000    0.0500598627544876  1.20715641293013), (-0.344503191645519  0.390376667574812   1.15887540716612); 
(-0.0931248606994074    0.267137193112796   1.24244644549763),(-0.183530493218807   0.384249186312578   1.14512014134276),.....
]
```

So as shown, I'll have a vector of pairs of points needed to be connected. So if anyone could please advise how this can be done in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to accomplish this.

```
%# Build an example matrix
A = [1 2 3; 0 0 0; 3 1 3; 2 0 2; 0 1 0];
Threshold = 3;

%# Calculate distance between all points
D = pdist2(A, A);

%# Discard any points with distance greater than threshold 
D(D > Threshold) = nan;
```

If you wish to extract an index of all observation pairs that are linked by a distance less than (or equal to) `Threshold`, as well as the corresponding distance (your question didn't specify what form you wanted the output to take, so I am essentially guessing here), then instead use the following:

```
%# Obtain a list of linear indices of observations less than or equal to TH
I1 = find(D <= Threshold);

%#Extract the actual distances, as well as the corresponding observation indices from A
[Obs1Index, Obs2Index] = ind2sub(size(D), I1);
DList = [Obs1Index, Obs2Index, D(I1)];
```

Note, `pdist2` uses Euclidean distance by default, but there are other options - see the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/pdist2.html).

**UPDATE:** Based on the OP's comments, the following code will express the output as a `K*6` matrix, where `K` is the number of distance measures less than the threshold value, and the first three columns of each row is the first data point (3 dimensions) and the second three columns of each row is the connected data point.

```
DList2 = [A(Obs1Index, :), A(Obs2Index, :)];
```

**SECOND UPDATE:** I have not made any assumptions on the distance measure in this answer. That is, I'm deliberately using `pdist2` in case your distance measure is not symmetric. However, if you are using a symmetric distance measure, then you could probably speed up the run-time by using `pdist` instead, although my indexing code would need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Colin for your answer, what I want to get is a list of pairs of points needed to be connected. Such as, [ (1 2 3), (0,0,0); (3,1,3),(2,0,2),.....] So as shown, I'll have a vector of pairs of points needed to be connected, so if you could please advise. Thanks alot

Comment: @user1460166 That's what I have shown in the answer below, haven't I?

Comment: @user1460166 If I understand correctly, then `DList2 = [A(Obs1Index, :), A(Obs2Index, :)];` will give you what you're after. Also, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

`Plot3` and `pdist2` can be used to achieve what you want.

```
D=pdist2(A,A);
T=0.2;
for i=1:7
  for j=i+1:7
    if D(i,j)<T & D(i,j)~=0
       i
       j
       plot3(A([i j],1),A([i j],2),A([i j],3));
       hold on;
       fprintf('line is plotted\n');
       pause;
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can further optimize this by ignoring `(j,i)` when `(i,j)` has already been plotted. I leave that upto you.

Comment: Why not use `pdist` - then you don't need to worry about getting every value twice. Incidentally, in your example use `i = 1:7` and `j = i+1:7` to avoid the problem of double-plotting.

Comment: @Floris I'm not sure if the OP explicitly specified a distance measure. Maybe the phrase "with a line" implies Euclidean distance, in which case `pdist` will be sufficient. But for full generality, one might choose to use `pdist2`, just in case the specified distance measure is not symmetric. That is the assumption I used in my answer anyway.